# One background attachment image is not showing

Tags: html, css, background-attachment

So i have this about page with multiple background attachment pics. All work besides one. I went through the code and cant seem to find out why one is not showing. Anyone got time to check the view source that would be great. http://idunlap.com/about.html

Comment: JSfiddle please. Please see [ask]

Comment: Is this your 404 page? http://error404.000webhost.com/?

Comment: Questions should include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I checked, and it seems that your image is not real. By that, I mean its URL is not real. It is error 404, or something like that. This is the URL that it redirects me to when I enter your missing image's URL: http://error404.000webhost.com/.

I'd say that you should try to upload the image again.